# How to check dllmain function is returning false

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a way to find while loading a cpp dll from an exe whether that dll is retuning false from DllMain method

Suppose I have an cpp exe and internally it is trying to load a cpp dll ,then if the cpp dll return false from DllMain method. Is there any logging in eventvwr or from any tool we can check it

Comment: LoadLibrary() will return FALSE.  GetLastError() returns error 1114, ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED, "A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed".  Just try it to ensure your user gets a decent error message, you'll need his help to keep your program usable.

Comment: I am getting the same error 1114 but intermittently. I have a c# project which loads a managed cpp dll. Cpp dll will load a third party native cpp dll.

Comment: Thanks for the response , I have a c# project which loads a managed cpp dll. Cpp dll will load a third party native cpp dll (not using load library function to load the native cpp dll , using header file and the lib file). While creating the object for the managed cpp dll then C# application is throw exception with error code 1114. From the error, can I assume that native dll dllmain function is returning false?

Comment: The question doesn't mention the CLR. The question also doesn't mention load-time linking (like your other comment). It appears that what you have asked for will not help you solve the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

If `DllMain` returns `false` in response to `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, `LoadLibrary()` returns NULL.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain).

> When the system calls the DllMain function with the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH
>   value, the function returns TRUE if it succeeds or FALSE if
>   initialization fails. If the return value is FALSE when DllMain is
>   called because the process uses the LoadLibrary function, LoadLibrary
>   returns NULL. (The system immediately calls your entry-point function
>   with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH and unloads the DLL.) If the return value is
>   FALSE when DllMain is called during process initialization, the
>   process terminates with an error. To get extended error information,
>   call GetLastError.
>
> When the system calls the DllMain function with any value other than
>   DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, the return value is ignored.

Comment: however *LoadLibrary* can return 0 and by another reason - say dll not found at all or not found it dependencies,another bitness of dll, etc. so if dll entry point return false - *Loadrary* will return 0. but visa versa not true. dll entry point can be not called at all. another question - what is really need - detect that load dll fail (by any reason) or exactly that it entry point return false

Comment: more exactly will be call `GetLastError()` (if dll load fail) and compare it with `ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED`. however still may be another dll return false (dependent) or another reason.

Comment: Thanks for the response , I have a c# project which loads a managed cpp dll. Cpp dll will load a third party native cpp dll (not using load library function to load the native cpp dll , using header file and the lib file). While creating the object for the managed cpp dll then C# application is throw exception with error code 1114. From the error, can I assume that native dll dllmain function is returning false?

Comment: @krish As RbMm pointed out there are maybe several reasons and I am also wondering why you so care the "dll dllmain function is returning false" instead of finding the real reason?

Comment: @krish Please check "[Handling and throwing exceptions in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/index?view=netframework-4.8)", [FileLoadException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileloadexception?view=netframework-4.8) (The exception that is thrown when a managed assembly is found but cannot be loaded.) and [FileNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filenotfoundexception?view=netframework-4.8) (The exception that is thrown when an attempt to access a file that does not exist on disk fails.).